# How to Stop a QThread That Runs a Blocking Forever Loop?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have some rough code that I've been experimenting with:

someserver.cpp (a GUI)

```
#include "server.h"
#include "ui_server.h"

Server::Server(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Server)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Server::~Server()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Server::onBtnStartClicked()
{
    QThread worker; 
    worker.start(); // Start worker thread that goes into an infinite loop with a blocking call
}

void Server::onBtnExitClicked()
{
    // How do I cleanly stop worker from running?
    QApplication::quit();
}
```

worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
}

void Worker::run()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        // a blocking IO call here like pipe, or msgrcv
        // process data received
    }
}
```

Since the worker thread runs in a forever loop with a blocking IO call, how will I be able to structure this so that when the Stop button is pressed in the GUI thread, the worker thread is stopped cleanly?

Answer (score 5):

You could of course put a boolean value within the for loop in `Worker::run()` checked every iteration, which breaks on ==true and is set by the gui Stop button.  Of course, this won't quit the thread while execution is blocked.

Probably better is to get rid of the `for` loop and use Qt's signals and slots to setup a callback function, connected to a signal like `QIODevice::readyRead()`.  These will be called only when there is information available in the socket/pipe whatever.  Any other time you'll be able to quit the thread with `QThread::exit()`.  You'll need to call `QThread::exec()` at some point as well to get the event loop going.

Comment: The problem is that the blocking call is a System V message queue so I don't think I'll be able to use something like QIODevice to setup a callback function for this.

Comment: @CodingDistrict I'm not familiar with those specifically, but surely there's some kind of callback apparatus for when a message is ready?  However that works, I would think you would be able to subclass `QLocalSocket` and make a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 3):

in infinity loop paste this code and enjoy...

```
QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(1);
while( QTime::currentTime() < dieTime ) {
    QCoreApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::AllEvents, 1);
}
```

don't forget

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QTime>
```

see you

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, you should set the parent for `Worker` to make it a child of another `QObject`, to clean it right way when the app is done, and create it on heap. i.e. dynamic way .

**Second**, simplest way to do what you want is to define slot which will set boolean member of `Worker` object and check it in each cycle to break endless loop. Don't forget to connect this slot to a right signal.

so you can put in constructor of the `Server` along the lines

```
QThread * worker = new QThread (this);
connect (this, SIGNAL(terminator()), worker, SLOT(terminate()));
```

in `Server` class declaration:

```
signals: 
  terminator();
```

in class `Worker` :

```
private: 
    bool terminate_; // don't forget initialize it to false
public slots: 
    void terminate(){terminate_ = true;}
```

and in the cycle:

```
if (terminate_) {/* .. do exit things...*/; return;
```

after that emit signal `terminator()` from server whenever you need.

If you will need more complicated management then simple stop, you will probably need to protect your state variable with a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the worker thread it is necessary to add "stop requested" boolean flag, which should be tested at the beginning of each iteration. Also the synchronization is needed to read/write value of this boolean flag.

Here is the draft version:

```
class Worker : public QThread {
    public:
        Worker() : stopRequested(false) {}

        void requestStop()
        {
            QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
            stopRequested = true;
        }

        void run()
        {
            forever
            {
                if (stopRequested())
                    break;

                // a blocking IO call here like pipe, or msgrcv
                // process data received
            }
        }

    private:
        bool stopRequested()
        {
            QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
            return stopRequested;
        }

        QMutex mutex;
        bool stopRequested;
};
```

Comment: And what the point of synchronization here? Oversynchronizing is not better then undersynchronizing. Also as @Matt Phillips mentioned, this does not help if thread is blocked in IO operation.

Comment: Also it is necessary to add the signal (something like "stopped") to the `Worker` class and emit right after forever loop. UI level class should be connected with the signal and receive the "stopped" notification.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#dtor.QThread) you have the explanation of you're problem, i think. When your application will end, you should do something like this :

```
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    m_thread->requestStop();
    m_thread->wait(); // Force the thread trying to destroy 
                      // an object of type MyClass, to wait 
                      // the end of the execution of m_thread
    delete m_thread;
}
```

[wait()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#wait) is the solution for your synchronisation problem. You could also change `requestStop()` to :

```
void requestStop()
{
    mutex.lock();
    stopRequested = true;
    mutex.unlock();
    wait();
}
```

Removing `QMutexLocker` is important to avoid a Deadlock situation.